# cordova create VS cordova-ios/bin/create

Tags: android, ios, cordova, xcode4.6, cordova-3

On OSX I want to create a PhoneGap app to run on iOS and Android.

I installed cordova (3.0.0) and phonegap (3.0.0-0.14.0) using npm.

Following the [CLI guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface) I can create my app using

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

then add platforms

```
cordova platform add ios
cordova platform add android
```

It works well but I'd like to use XCode as IDE. I read the [IOS platform guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_tools.md.html#iOS%20Command-line%20Tools) and saw I can create my app using

```
./path/to/cordova-ios/bin/create /path/to/hello com.example.hello HellowWorld
```

I can't execute that command if the folder already exists, so I removed it first. I then tried adding android to it but it doesn't work (`Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.`). I then noticed that the content of the directories are really different depending on the tool used.

Is there an easy way to create an XCode project and still be able to use the CLI to build for Android and iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a project for ios using the CLI **against the bin** directory of the ios platform as in your example EXCEPT, I had to create an empty folder first. Try this..

./create ~/My-Project/name of empty project folder com.example.appname. "Project Name"

Comment: I was also able to create a project for IOS like that (not sure if I first removed the target folder or just emptied it), but then I can't add the android platform. I would want to have both: ios and android platform, as well as an XCode project (automatically created for me by cordova).

Comment: I might be mistaken, but i've used the same synatx for android as well but obviously I would be running the command against the bin directory of the android platform and instead of using cordova like you have done I've been using 'Phonegap!

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- create a project using `cordova create projectname`
- add ios support with `cordova platform add ios`
- navigate to `projectname/platforms/ios` and open the `.xcodeproj` file in XCode

to use XCode as the IDE.

`cordova platform add ios` uses the `create` script under the covers.

The issue you will run into is that if you make changes to the html, css, or js files under `projectname/platforms/ios`, you will have to manually push those changes back to `projectname/www`.  Or you can only make changes to `projectname/www` and use `cordova prepare` to push them to your ios directory (and your android directory).

You'd also need to decide how you want to handle version control--will you do it yourself with a command line client, or within your IDE?